# Spring Cloud Data Flow > Stream > Source throws UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION when deploying in K8s but working in local deployment

Tags: apache-kafka, kubernetes, spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to run a "Hello, world" Spring Cloud Data Flow stream based on the very simple example explained at http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/. I'm able to create a simple source and sink and run it on my local SCDF server using Kafka, so until here everything is correct.

Now, I'm trying to deploy it in my private cloud based on the instructions listed at http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_getting_started. Using this deployment I'm able to deploy a simple "time | log" out-of-the-box stream with no problems, but my example fails.

Specific versions are:

- Docker version 1.13.1, build 092cba3
- Hyperkube 1.5.5
- SCDF 1.2.0.M2
- zookeeper 3.4.9-1757313, built on 08/23/2016 06:50 GMT
- Kafka 0.10.1.1

Source artifact logs are:

> 2017-04-06T11:05:07.429204866Z 2017-04-06 11:05:07,428  INFO main-SendThread(10.0.0.181:2181) o.a.z.ClientCnxn:876 - Socket connection established to 10.0.0.181/10.0.0.181:2181, initiating session
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.440381666Z 2017-04-06 11:05:07,439  INFO main-SendThread(10.0.0.181:2181) o.a.z.ClientCnxn:1299 - Session establishment complete on server 10.0.0.181/10.0.0.181:2181, sessionid = 0x15b155ef61e014a, negotiated timeout = 10000
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.740130495Z 2017-04-06 11:05:07,737  INFO main o.a.k.c.p.ProducerConfig:180 - ProducerConfig values: 
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.740160464Z     acks = 1
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.740163408Z     batch.size = 16384
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.740165226Z     block.on.buffer.full = false
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.740166942Z     bootstrap.servers = [10.0.0.213:9092]
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.740168741Z     buffer.memory = 33554432
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.740170545Z     client.id = 
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.740172245Z     compression.type = none
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.740173971Z     connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.740175706Z     interceptor.classes = null 
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.744179899Z     reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.744181600Z     request.timeout.ms = 30000
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.744183356Z     retries = 0
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.744185083Z     retry.backoff.ms = 100
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.744186754Z     sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.744188494Z     sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.744190205Z     sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.744191916Z     sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.744193763Z     sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.744195432Z     sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.744197163Z     security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.744198789Z     send.buffer.bytes = 131072
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.744200522Z     ssl.cipher.suites = null
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.744202328Z     ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.744204161Z     ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.744205837Z     ssl.key.password = null
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.744207544Z     ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.744212464Z     ssl.keystore.location = null
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.744214272Z     ssl.keystore.password = null
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.744216025Z     ssl.keystore.type = JKS
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.744217647Z     ssl.protocol = TLS
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.744219234Z     ssl.provider = null
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.744220987Z     ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.744222666Z     ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.744224359Z     ssl.truststore.location = null
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.744226022Z     ssl.truststore.password = null
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.744228171Z     ssl.truststore.type = JKS
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.744230006Z     timeout.ms = 30000
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.744231705Z     value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.744233544Z 
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.837193978Z 2017-04-06 11:05:07,834  WARN main o.a.k.c.p.ProducerConfig:188 - The configuration 'key.deserializer' was supplied but isn't a known config.
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.837221870Z 2017-04-06 11:05:07,835  WARN main o.a.k.c.p.ProducerConfig:188 - The configuration 'value.deserializer' was supplied but isn't a known config.
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.929207703Z 2017-04-06 11:05:07,926  INFO main o.a.k.c.u.AppInfoParser:83 - Kafka version : 0.10.1.1
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.929239636Z 2017-04-06 11:05:07,927  INFO main o.a.k.c.u.AppInfoParser:84 - Kafka commitId : f10ef2720b03b247
>       2017-04-06T11:05:08.228817026Z 2017-04-06 11:05:08,228  WARN kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1 o.a.k.c.NetworkClient:600 - Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 0 : {output=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}
>       2017-04-06T11:05:08.436574800Z 2017-04-06 11:05:08,435  WARN kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1 o.a.k.c.NetworkClient:600 - Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 1 : {output=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}

And Zookepeer logs are:

> 2017-04-06T11:04:38.000953447Z 2017-04-06 11:04:38,000 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2181)::PrepRequestProcessor@487] - Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x15b155ef61e0148
>       2017-04-06T11:05:04.939356606Z 2017-04-06 11:05:04,938 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@192] - Accepted socket connection from /10.1.98.5:48180
>       2017-04-06T11:05:04.940666418Z 2017-04-06 11:05:04,939 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:ZooKeeperServer@928] - Client attempting to establish new session at /10.1.98.5:48180
>       2017-04-06T11:05:04.943859474Z 2017-04-06 11:05:04,943 [myid:] - INFO  [SyncThread:0:ZooKeeperServer@673] - Established session 0x15b155ef61e0149 with negotiated timeout 10000 for client /10.1.98.5:48180
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.325929074Z 2017-04-06 11:05:07,325 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2181)::PrepRequestProcessor@487] - Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x15b155ef61e0149
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.342876962Z 2017-04-06 11:05:07,341 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1008] - Closed socket connection for client /10.1.98.5:48180 which had sessionid 0x15b155ef61e0149
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.429909440Z 2017-04-06 11:05:07,429 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@192] - Accepted socket connection from /10.1.98.5:48182
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.429933377Z 2017-04-06 11:05:07,429 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:ZooKeeperServer@928] - Client attempting to establish new session at /10.1.98.5:48182
>       2017-04-06T11:05:07.441158222Z 2017-04-06 11:05:07,439 [myid:] - INFO  [SyncThread:0:ZooKeeperServer@673] - Established session 0x15b155ef61e014a with negotiated timeout 10000 for client /10.1.98.5:48182
>       2017-04-06T11:05:29.695276997Z 2017-04-06 11:05:29,694 [myid:] - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@357] - caught end of stream exception
>       2017-04-06T11:05:29.695325790Z EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x15b155ef61e014a, likely client has closed socket
>       2017-04-06T11:05:29.695328912Z     at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228)
>       2017-04-06T11:05:29.695331119Z     at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:203)
>       2017-04-06T11:05:29.695333009Z     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>       2017-04-06T11:05:29.696333706Z 2017-04-06 11:05:29,696 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1008] - Closed socket connection for client

I dont find any log in Kafka at the moment of the exception.

Code snippet for the source class is

```
package xxxx;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Source;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.InboundChannelAdapter;
import org.springframework.integration.core.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class HelloNitesApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloNitesApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = Source.OUTPUT)
    public MessageSource<String> timerMessageSource()
    {
        return () -> new GenericMessage<>("Hello " + new SimpleDateFormat().format(new Date()));
    }
```

So, the pod containing the stream source keeps crashing in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the fact that the property "spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=XXX" is ignored by my implementation and I deleted the topic "output" before the execution as I expected it to write in the topic specified by the property.

After I redeployed everything the source works as the topic is created properly, although inserting the messages in "output" topic instead the one specified by he property I defined.